# How to remove text from a string array when they're unknown?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I know how to remove elements from an array if i know what they are.

The "client" in this array is an string input by the user. I want to remove the first 2 words, but I don't know what they'll be. Its always different.

```
string[] words = Receipt.Split(' ',',','-');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *always* want to remove the first two, LINQ probably provides the simplest approach:

```
string allButFirstTwoWords = words.Skip(2).ToArray(); // Or ToList, or nothing...
```

Note that you can't "remove" values from the array itself, as an array always has a fixed size after creation. The code above creates a *new* array with all but the first two words.

Of course, you can do it all in one go:

```
string[] words = Receipt.Split(' ', ',', '-').Skip(2).ToArray();
```

Personally I'd usually use a `List<string>` instead, as it's more flexible:

```
List<string> words = Receipt.Split(' ', ',', '-').Skip(2).ToList();
```

If you're just going to iterate over it, you don't need to convert it to an array or a list at all:

```
IEnumerable<string> words = Receipt.Split(' ', ',', '-').Skip(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] words = Receipt.Split(' ',',','-').Skip(2).ToArray();
```